# Opening Youtube Annotation Link (in an iFrame embedded youtube video) that plays in that same embedded iFrame (and doesn't open to a new page)

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

Here's what I have now:

```
<div id ="videoBox">
<div class="youtubeVideo"> 
<iframe id="vid_frame" width="100%" height=100% src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbbKjDjMDok?rel=0&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

With several roll-over images they can choose from:

```
 <a href="#"><div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='http://youtube.com/embed/tbbKjDjMDok?rel=0&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'"><div id="felizTape">
 <img src="hcimages/feliz.png" alt="Feliz Navidad" width="100%" height="100%"/> </div></div></a>
```

The idea is that I have a little TV & tapes graphic that the video plays in on the page - when a user clicks one of the stack of tapes, a new video opens in the videoBox div.  The problem is that when a user finishes watching a video in the embed, we give them the option to watch other videos (see the annotated links at the end) - but that opens up youtube in a new tab.  I'm looking for a way to in the same 'vidoBox' div when they click it from the suggested box.  Any thoughts?

THANKS!